# In C++ .is triangle area showing zero??? why?

Tags: c++, area, dev-c++

The area of triangle is showing zero in the output, why is that??
What have i done wrong??

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int Base, Height, Area;

  // >>> Is anything wrong with the formula??
  Area = (0.5) * Height * Base;

  cout << "To find the Area of Triangle" << endl << endl;

  // Base
  cout << "Enter Base length:";
  cin >> Base;
  cout << endl;

  // Height
  cout << "Enter Height length";
  cin >> Height;
  cout << endl << endl;

  cout << "Your Base Length is:" << Base << endl;
  cout << "Your Height Length is:" << Height << endl;

  // calculating area of triangle

  // >>> This is the part output is zero
  cout << "Area of the triangle is :" << Area << endl;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, you cannot store fractional values in an integer.  Secondly, `Area = (0.5)*Height*Base;` performs a calculation using two uninitialized values.  It appears that you're under the false impression that this line of code makes `Area` some kind of magic "formula" that will perform this calculation whenever you request its value.  That is incorrect.  Move that line of code to the point _after_ you have read `Base` and `Height` from the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have a computed value you *must* compute it with any changes made to the values involved. Unlike algebra where `x = y * 2` means "`x` is by definition `y` times two", in C++ it means "assign to `x` the value of `y` times `2` *as it is right now*" and has no bearing on the future.

For something calculated you use a function:

```
int Area(const int Height, const int Base) {
  return 0.5 * Height * Base;
}
```

Where now you can call it:

```
cout<<"Area of the triangle according to your measurements is :"<<Area(Height, Base)<<endl<<endl;
```

Comment: @paddy Misread the question, so thanks for the note and fix. Improved it further.

Comment: @Gowtham_M please read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)